# I'm having trouble setting up my sql tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So, I keep running into problems with my (oracle) sql. Here's my current one

```
alter table cowner
add foreign key (serialno) references car(serialno):
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

with the tables in question being

```sql
create table cowner(
serialno varchar(24),
tdate date,
owned varchar(24),
regno varchar(24),
destroy varchar(50),
primary key(serialno, tdate)
);

create table car(
serialno varchar(24),
model varchar(24),
pyear date,
primary key (serialno),
foreign key (model) references cmodel(model) 
);

create table cmodel(
model varchar(24),
manname varchar(24),
primary key(model, manname)
foreign key(manname) references manufact(manname)
);
```

I read from another SO that it could be that I have reserved words somewhere for column names, but I'm not sure what those would be.

Comment: what are you trying to do. To create a foreign key use "alter table table_name1 add constraint fk_name FOREIGN KEY (column_name) references table_name2 (column_name)"

Comment: What about the table `cmodel`?

Answer (score 1):

The ORA-2270 error is a straightforward logical error: it happens when the columns we list in the foreign key do not match a primary key or unique constraint on the parent table. Common reasons for this are

- the parent lacks a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint altogether.
- the foreign key clause references the wrong column in the parent table.
- the parent table's constraint is a compound key and we haven't
  referenced all the columns in the foreign key statement.

In your table cowner column name destroy is the reserved word.
Use "" to name such columns.

Comment: _"table cowner column name destroy is the reserved word. Use "" to name such columns."_  While this may techincally fix the issue, it is bad advice.  Using double-quotes to create a name means you have to use them _every_ time you reference it.  Bad enough in itself, but even worse when used to get around trying to use a reserved word for an object name.  Much better to simply not try to use a reserved word in the first place.  I recommend all column names be in the format 'adjective_noun'.  This eliminates the 'reserved word' issue, _and_ makes them more 'self documenting'.

Comment: I deleted the word 'destroy', but I'm still getting the same problem